# Invoke Derived types method from List with basetypes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've got the following classes. (State, DataState (inherits from state with Template type), StateMachine)

In StateMachine there is a method 'addState' that adds a State to a list. When i now invoke the OnStateUpdate message from a DataState added via addState method. The methods from base class State are executed. How can i execute the methods from DataState or classes that derive from DataState.

My goal is to have one list to manage all those types. Coming from C# i know that it is possible there. What is the c++ way?

Thank you

```
#include <list>
#ifndef STATEMACHINE_H
#define STATEMACHINE_H

class State
{
public:
    /* Use this for initialization*/
    virtual void OnStateEnter(){};
    /* Use this to update the state*/
    virtual StateResult OnStateUpdate(){ return StateResult::NotImplemented; };
    /*  */
    virtual void OnStateExit(){};
};

template <class T>
class DataState : public State
{
protected:
    T data;

public:
    DataState(T data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
};

class StateMachine
{
private:
    std::list<State> _states;
    State* _activeState;

public:
    void addState(const State& newState);

    void loop();
};

#endif // STATEMACHINE_H
```

Comment: Store `std::unique_ptr<State>`. The call must be via a reference or pointer to occur virtually. If you store by value as you are here, the instances get sliced and _are_ `State`s; the derived identity/functionality is lost.

Comment: `_states` in `StateMachine` store `State` instance _per value_, meaning you will be slicing objects provided to `addState(...)` when copied into the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)